# Verify your SQL Server DML scripts

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dml

I do a lot of insert, update, deletes by forwarding my SQL to a senior member as I don't have DB write access.

Could you suggest me some ways to verify these scripts against the tables?

Usually the issues are columns mismatch, since our tables have too many columns

Ideally if I can put my DML T-SQL in another script to be 100% sure that it will execute.

Thanks

**Update:**
Until I have the proposed environment I have acquired a work around which is serving the purpose.
I use [select * into #temp from table] and test all my scripts against it. Columns can be specified if needed and errors are helpful in writing/verifying an executable DMLscript

Comment: The "Show Query Plan" (Ctrl-L) command should catch any column, syntax or other compiler-visible issues.  But you should still get a development/test database.

Answer (score 2):

Run it in your development (non-production) environment which mirrors the database structure you have in production and has data representative of the production environment (properly scrubbed).

Comment: don't have that. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Then I suggest that you get a development environment set up in which to work. Where do you write & test your code before making it live?

Comment: on my location machine (sql server) with Read access only and send it to my colleague who has write access for execution

Comment: If you have no development/test environment for your system at all, then you are playing Russian Roulette every time you make a change to your production system. Any professional environment where software is being built or implemented needs to have at least one non-production setup for testing and situations like this. If you don't have one, it's only a matter of time before you have a massive problem that hurts the business.

Comment: 100% agree.  Copying a database with Backup and Restore from production to development or even to your own desktop is just to darn easy for developers not to do it.  The cost/effort is minimal and the benefits are immense, so it's a no-brainer.

Comment: Copying a database to your computer should only be done as an absolute last resort (and even then, not undertaken lightly). There are far too many ways for data to be "lost" in this way. You do not want to have your laptop stolen out of your car and then see your employer on the evening news due to a data breach.